# Using devextreme vue components, is there any way to customize the default buttons' label, like "OK" and "Cancel"?

Tags: devexpress

After going through much of the API documentation of the TagBox component, I still haven't figured out how to customize the "OK" and "Cancel" labels for localization and better UX.

Are there any props that I haven't figured out yet that exist for this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You could change get the button elements with jquery and change the label, this works when the content is ready or when the dropdown is open, check the events.

Or

Implement your own buttons:

```
$('...').dxTagBox({
   items: [...],
   showSelectionControls: true,
   applyValueMode: 'useButtons',

   dropDownOptions: {

       toolbarItems: [
       {
           location: "center",
           options: {
               text: 'CUSTOM OK', 
               onClick: function() {
                  // Check documentation
                  // Get selected items
                  // Apply to the tagBox instance
                  }, 
            
              },
           shortcut: "done",
           toolbar: "bottom" 
       }
           ...
       ]

   }
});
```